# How can I change the way of handling exceptions in my java project in a better way?

Tags: java, architecture, exception, eclipse-rcp

I have to refactor a Java program created with Eclipse RCP. My predecessor handed over a ViewPart Implementation through several calls down to the class I want to write Unit Tests for. The ViewPart is handed over for exception handling purposes. Every time an error occurs the error message will be written onto the ViewPart's StatusLineManager.

What I want to do now is to change this *exception handling* process, because it causes me a lot of problems when I want to make my Unit Tests.

Is there a way to pass these Exceptions to the ViewPart without handing it down over several method calls?

My initial ideas to create some kind of *ExceptionMessenger* class that will be initialized every time an exception occurs. But I didn't find a way to access the ViewPart then.

**edit**
code example:

```
class A {
    void func() {
         B.funcB(arg, arg1, arg2, ViewPart view):
    }
}

class B {
      void funcB(arg, arg1, arg2, ViewPart view) {
           C.funcC(arg, arg1, ViewPart view);
      }
}

class C {
    void funcC(arg, arg1, ViewPart view) {
        try{
             doSomeThing():
        catch(Exception e) {
            doSomeErrorMessages(e, view);
        }
     }

    void doSomeErrorMessages(e, ViewPart view) {
        SomeOtherClass.writeToStatusLine( StatusCategory.Processing, e.getMessage(), view); 
    }
 }

class SomeOtherClass {
    void writeToStatusLine(final StatusCategory category, final String message, final ViewPart view) {
    IActionBars bars = view.getViewSite().getActionBars();
        IStatusLineManager statusLineManagerRef = bars.getStatusLineManager();
        statusLineManagerRef.setErrorMessage(null); // clear any error msg

        doWhatEver();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Without specific code examples, it is very difficult to work out what your specific problem is.

Comment: I wouldn't have a problem with `handing it down over several method calls`.  Your IDE should help you maintain this chain of exceptions.

Comment: @PeterLawrey well, I do not really know what you wanna tell me

Comment: @beny23 added some code above. can not provide the real code, so this is some dummy code.

Comment: Maybe I should mention that ViewPart is a class provided by Eclipse

Comment: Maybe Peter means the the chain of methods that an Exception passes when being thrown?

Comment: My point was, throw exceptions up through the methods and let your IDE maintain the list of the `throws` clause.  This is very simple to handle in unit tests and calling code.

Comment: @Peter: That's what I thought. I think for exceptions that are unchecked and thrown upwards anyway, that's a good advise. Otherwise, I'd consider the constraints in the middle of my post...

Comment: @DaveBall With the help of the IDE, it is usually not a problem using checked exceptions either. A hack to throwing checked exceptions past interfaces which cannot be changed is `Thread.currentThread().stop(myCheckedException);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your task correctly, there are two parts where you are dealing with exceptions:

- Java's **exception handling** when some exceptional behaviour occurs. For this, you should stick to what Java offers you, as described, e.g., in [Josh Bloch's Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683), Item 57 ( Use exceptions only for exceptional conditions).
- **Visualisation of exceptions** in your tool (by `ViewPart`). Since this is not part of exception handling to recover or otherwise cope with exceptional conditions, I would deliberately not use Java's exception handling for that, i.e. avoid misusing exception handling for control flow. Hence I think your predecessor's design to pass down the `ViewPart` to then pass the Exceptions as parameters to your `ViewPart` is good.

An alternative would be to **let the exceptions get thrown upward** and then at some sensible border of layer/framework do the visualisation. But

- be careful not to mix the two parts of dealing with exceptions listed above
- if you are dealing with checked exceptions and can handle them far down in your call hierarchy, this will make your code much uglier than passing down `ViewPart` (and definitely mix the two parts listed above).

What are your problems when **unit testing**?

- If the ViewPart is making trouble: [mock it](http://www.sizovpoint.com/2009/03/java-mock-frameworks-comparison.html).
- If passing the ViewPart as parameter is annoying you: use some framework for your dependency injection, e.g. [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/search/google?query=dependency+injection&output=xml_no_dtd&client=google-csbe&cx=009687201310241541466%3Azerjfa_shxo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&op=Search) or [Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/).
- If an alternative visualisation/handling of the Exceptions is making trouble: might a [(junit-)rule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/package-summary.html) solve the problem?

Comment: actually I don't know how to mock it up.

Comment: @keinabel: I've added a link explaining mocking and listing Java mock frameworks.